# What is the input for adjusted_rand_score and adjusted_mutual_info_score?

Tags: scikit-learn, data-science

I read the documentation and I get that it is labels_true and labels_pred but in what form do they have to be?

For the labels_pred I use `kmeans.labels_`  which is an numpy array containing 0, 1, 2 or 3.
For the labels_true I use `top100.Genre`. Top100 is a dataframe which contains movies with different genres, there are 4 total genres. I read somewhere that I can just insert these two labels, and that the two score measures will find a way to assign the numbers to a genre.

Is this true? The values I get are slightly above 0 (like 0.014) so that doesn't say much to me.
Or do I have to convert top100.Genre to a numpy array as well and change the names of the genres to 0, 1, 2 and 3? And how would I assign each number?

Answer (score 1):

I think the score measures will find a way to match the assigned labels and predicted ones. As per the Scikit-learn documentation the input should be an array. In this case assign class labels for the genres such as 0,1,2,3 like you have mentioned. They can be assigned randomly.

Also the Scikit_learn documentation mentions that the score need not be a perfect 0, but close to 0. So a score of 0.014 is acceptable.

The link below has a some good information:
https://esigma6.wordpress.com/2018/11/03/2-3-9-clustering-performance-evaluation/